# In SQL Plus, getting extra trailing spaces for second column when using lpad in Oracle 11g and above version

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, sqlplus

## **Sample Code:**

```
spool "xy2.dat"
set heading off
set pause off
set termout off
set linesize 164
select  'start', lpad(current_date,12,'0'), current_date, 'gap', current_date, 'end' from dual
/
spool off
```

Oracle 10g Output:

```
start 00021-DEC-20 21-DEC-20 gap 21-DEC-20 end
```

Oracle 11g and above output:

```
start 00021-DEC-20                                     21-DEC-20 gap 21-DEC-20 end
```

Seems weird output in SQL Plus for Oracle 11g above, do we have any root cause for this different behaviour.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on my 11g.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like even though the column names are not displayed (HEADING OFF) they still take their space.

Since you dont' need the column names, an easy solution might be to use short column aliases:

```
SET HEADING OFF
SELECT
    'start' AS c1,
    LPAD( CURRENT_DATE, 12, '0' ) AS c2,
    CURRENT_DATE AS c3,
    'gap' AS c4,
    CURRENT_DATE AS c5,
    'end' AS c6
FROM dual
```

Result:

```
start 00021-DEC-20 21-DEZ-20 gap 21-DEZ-20 end
```

This is what it looked like before:

```
start   00021-DEC-20              21-DEZ-20    gap   21-DEZ-20      end
```